# Javascript onblur eventlistener not working

Tags: javascript

I have an input field which I show on clicking of a button, and I am trying to hide the input field again when the field is not focused anymore:
This is the field:

```
<span class="button-search"><input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="input"></span>
```

And this is the js code:

```
function expand(action) {
      searchContainer.classList[action]('expanded');
  }
  button.addEventListener('click', function() { expand('add');input.focus(); }, false);
  input.addEventListener('onblur', function() { expand('remove') }, true);
```

But, for some reason it is not working, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: When using `addEventListener` you do not use "on" as part of the event name. That is used for the element's event property / attribute name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `blur` instead of `onblur`
Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur